# On Perron's formula with remainder

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I am following Tenenbaum's *Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory* to prove Perron's formula with remainder. Particularly, in section II.2.1 the book states that

$$
\left|\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds\right|\le{x^\kappa\over T\log x}
$$

where $k>\kappa>0$ and $x>1$, but when I perform integration by parts, I get

$$
\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds={x^\kappa\over\log x}\left({x^{iT}\over\kappa+iT}-{x^{-k+iT}\over\kappa-k+iT}\right)+{1\over\log x}\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{x^s\over s^2}\mathrm ds
$$

Now taking absolute value on both side, the equation becomes

$$
\left|\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds\right|\le{x^\kappa\over T\log x}+{1\over|\kappa-k+iT|}+{1\over\log x}\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{\mathrm ds\over|s|^2}
$$

Apparently, my bound is much more loose than that of the book, and I wonder what I can do more to make the bounds more tight.

Comment: @user10354138 Edited. Thanks for that reminder

Comment: Try using the triangle inequality and thus taking the modulus of the integrand first, before integrating. (and remember you're just looking for an upper bound, not an exact evaluation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Greg Martin's comment, I get that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds\right|
&=\left|\int_{\kappa-k}^\kappa{x^{t+iT}\over t+iT}\mathrm dt\right| \\
&\le\int_{\kappa-k}^\kappa{x^t\over|t+iT|}\mathrm dt
\end{aligned}
$$

By the property of right triangle, we see that $|t+iT|\ge T$, so

$$
\left|\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds\right|\le\frac1T\left|\int_{\kappa-k}^\kappa x^t\mathrm dt\right|\le{x^\kappa-x^{\kappa-k}\over T|\log x|}
$$

Since $x>1$ and $\kappa>k$, we have $x^{\kappa-k}<x^\kappa$. Consequently, we obtain Tenenbaum's bound that

$$
\left|\int_{\kappa-k+iT}^{\kappa+iT}{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds\right|\le{x^\kappa\over T\log x}
$$